# Performance monitor access is denied

Tags: virtualization, performance-monitoring, hyper-v-server-2016

I've been seaching for about the last 5 hour about perforamce monitor and how it works, and it has been a pain. I'm trying to get Performance monitor working on Windows Hyper-v Server 2016. I also have a other server just a normal server with GUI.

It first took me about 12 hour just to get windows installed (But that is not part of the question). Now i have a few VMs running not a lot just for testing things out.

I when from XenServer(A Horrible hypervisor by the way) To Hyper-v. But all i want is hyper-v with nice performance charts. I really was hoping i was not asking too much.

Now that the back story is a bit done. I have server manager with both servers on them. I can access both servers from there.

Now come the problems. When i right click on the server manager and i got to computer management, and perforamance manager. I can go to performance monoitor and i can see the live perforamance.

Cool that works but from that point it all goes south. If i try and create a "Data Collection set" Under user defined. The next button is disabled.

Now my tought okay well let me go to performance monitor it self. So i go there press "Connect to remote server" Fill in the server name(Which is a bit weird cant select a user) and i press connect. Error: Access is denied. Greate tried googling for about 5 hours. Im about to give up and install ESXi.(What i really dont want to do).

Oh i just remember just to say, on the other server it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming these are in a workgroup as you haven't said anything about a domain. Have you verified the appropriate firewall rules are enabled? 
Also, you need to add the server you want to manage to the trustedhosts list.

```
Set-Item wsman:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts Server01 -Concatenate -force
```

Then you may need to override the UAC restrictions.

```
New-ItemProperty -Name LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy -path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Currentversion\Policies\System -propertytype DWord -value 1
```

You can read more about managing computers in a workgroup on this [page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-manager/add-servers-to-server-manager#add-and-manage-servers-in-workgroups).

Comment: The first one is already done. I did it a lot of times also for getting server manager to work. That works But the second one is teling me the "property already exists" So i dont know if i already did it or if i need to replace anything.